# AngularJs change location after save

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble changing location after I save a new customer in an angular.
Here's my controller.

```
function CustomersNewController($scope, $location, Customer) {
  $scope.selected_customer = '';

  $scope.submit = function() {
    rails_customer = new Customer({customer: $scope.new_customer});
    rails_customer.$save({format: 'json'},function(data, getResponseHeaders) {
      $location.path(data.id + '/edit/') ;
    }, function(data, getResponseHeaders) {
      console.log("ERROR");
    });
  };
}
```

The customer saves to the database fine.  The problem is that I can't get the id of the object that was just saved in order to redirect to the edit page.

The 'data' object is populated but it looks like this:

```
b {customer: Object, $then: function, $resolved: true, $get: function, $save: function…}
$resolved: true
$then: function (callback, errback) {
customer: Object
```

Can anyone give me a hand on how to dig the id out of the returned data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your data object it should be

```
$location.path(data.customer.id + '/edit');
```

Comment: Doh!  That's what I get for coding at 1am!  Thanks!